# Unable to position my label in TCK/TK via GRID

Tags: grid, position, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am setting up a TK screen in TCL. A label in 1st row and an image in 2nd row are set up correctly as expected. But When I wanted to add a label just next to the image, its always showing it on the right extreme. I have even anchoring the label using 'nw' and sticking the frame also as 'nw', but the behavior remains the same. Can someone help?

```
package require Tk
package require Img

wm title . "Operator Login"

# Top corner label
ttk::frame .f0
tk::label .f0.l0 -text "Sales Application" -foreground blue \
    -textvariable "Total" -font {Helvetica -18 bold} -anchor ne

# Logo frame
ttk::frame .f1
tk::label .f1.l0 -textvariable "Total" -anchor nw
image create photo imgobj -file "C:/.../.../flowers.bmp"
.f1.l0 configure -image imgobj

# Login frame
ttk::frame .f2
tk::label .f2.l0 -text "ID " -foreground blue -textvariable "ID" \
    -font {Helvetica -13 bold} -anchor nw

# GRID Management
grid .f0 -column 0 -row 0 -columnspan 25 -sticky ne
grid .f0.l0 -column 0 -row 0 -columnspan 25

grid .f1 -column 0 -row 2 -columnspan 4 -rowspan 5 -sticky nsew -pady 5 -padx 5
grid .f1.l0 -column 0 -row 2 -columnspan 4 -rowspan 5 -sticky nsew -pady 5 -padx 5

grid .f2 -column 5 -row 2 -sticky w
grid .f2.l0 -column 5 -row 2

grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 1
grid columnconfigure .f1 0 -weight 1
grid rowconfigure .f1 0 -weight 1
```

Comment: Do you mean it 'sticks' to the right when you resize the window? Is it fine when you first open the application without resizing? If so, you should use `grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 0` on the 3rd to last line. Otherwise, can you provide a picture of where you would like it to appear?

Comment: @Jerry: Yes, my application is going to be a full-screen application. When I make the weight to zero, the label "ID" has come next to the image. But my first-row label is becoming left-aligned whereas it should be right-aligned.

It should be like 

1st row -> Label right-aligned spanning 25 columns
2nd row -> image left-aligned spanning first 4 columns followed by a label of two column span.